# SQL Server job runs forever after server restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jobs

One of our ETL servers had to be restarted and a job was in the middle of execution. It was on the 2nd of 6 steps and now the job agent shows that it has been running for 15 hours back on step 1.

Currently running SQL Server 2012 (11.0.3).

Most of the fields in the Log File Viewer are blank, except for duration, job name and this message:

> In Progress

We haven't stopped the job yet.

- Can anyone explain why this is happening?
- Is the best practice before any server restart to stop/disable all jobs?

`sp_whoisactive` showed the job running but there wasn't any CPU load or anything like that. Unfortunately, I am not able to share the code, most I can divulge is it's a 6 step process running a SQL server package.

Comment: It would have been best to stop the ETL process before restarting, if the restart was planned or known to be occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why a query could take longer after a restart but the most likely (assuming it is still running) would be that the plan cache has been cleared and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Hi thanks for replies-
Josh - I think this is the issue. I don't think the job is actually running this entire time. It feels more like it wasn't given a formal completion time so the SQL Server thinks it is still running. Disk was not even close to full so I think it just got hung up. Maybe this just needs to be ticketed to Microsoft, and it's a bug. There wasn't a subsequent system crash or disk full error. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

while the job history will still show the job in progress but in actual the sql server agent job becomes idle after the server was restarted. this impact the execution of sql agent jobs